# NotDisplaying Grid when trying to do using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jqgrid

Data in grid is not dispalying .Servlet code is the folowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide values for missing properties like: page, records, rows , total.

so make the following update: 
First:

```
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "0", root: "model"},
```

and the return json from servlet should be like this:

```
{"model":[{Your Above Json row},{...},{...}], "page":1, "records": 987654321, "rows": 987654321, "total": 1}
```

987654321 stands for size of your consultants list.